# Why doesn't armature move with keyframes?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I've got this animated animal thingy with keyframes, but when it moves the armature doesn't move with it, does anyone know how to fix that?
[image]

Comment: This could be a number of things, depending on how your relationships are set up. Usually, the mesh object is meant to be parented to the armature, so of course moving the mash won’t cause the armature to follow it.

Comment: 1. Check if you parented with automatic weight the armature into the mesh.
2. If that doesn't work enable the record button to record bones keyframes